# Entity Framework piece together LINQ to Entity Queries

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I need some help here.  I am trying to make a portion of an EF Query reusable.

```
var query = from sr in SomeEFRepository.SelectAll()
            select new {
               KeyValuePivotField1 = (from kvd in sr.KeyValueData
                                      where kvd.KeyName == "FieldName1"
                                      select kvd.Value).FirstOrDefault(),
               KeyValuePivotField2 = (from kvd in sr.KeyValueData
                                      where kvd.KeyName == "FieldName2"
                                      select kvd.Value).FirstOrDefault(),
               KeyValuePivotField3 = (from kvd in sr.KeyValueData
                                      where kvd.KeyName == "FieldName3"
                                      select kvd.Value).FirstOrDefault()
            }
```

If you look you can see that I am constantly repeating myself with the following code.

```
(from kvd in sr.KeyValueData
where kvd.KeyName == "SomeFieldName"
select kvd.Value).FirstOrDefault(),
```

How can I make a method that EF will recognize in order to do something like this?

```
var query = from sr in SomeEFRepository.SelectAll()
            select new {
               KeyValuePivotField1 = GetFieldFromKeyValue("FieldName1"),
               KeyValuePivotField2 = GetFieldFromKeyValue("FieldName2"),
               KeyValuePivotField3 = GetFieldFromKeyValue("FieldName3"),
            }
```

Any suggestions will help.  I have been reading about Expression Trees but not sure if 
that would be a good approach or even possible.

Note: I am using EF 5.0 with DBContext.

Comment: Have you thought about an extension method?

Comment: @Justin No I have not.  But Any reference you could provide me may assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a great answer and article to my troubles.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/402594/Black-Art-LINQ-expressions-reuse

A nice NuGet Package LinqExpressionProjection 1.0.0 that is perfect for my problem.

http://nuget.org/packages/LinqExpressionProjection

Answer (score 0):

Extension methods seem like a good fit for this. I don't know exactly what you are doing so this is a example

Customer class

```
public class Customer{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }

   public override string ToString()
   {
       return string.Format("Customer is {0} {1}", this.FirstName, this.LastName);
   }
}
```

CustomerExtensionMethod

```
//Class MUST be static
public static class CustomerExtensionMethods
{
    //Method MUST be static and use this keyword to be an extension method
    public static Customer GetByFirstName(this IEnumerable<Customer> source, string value)
    {
        return source.Where(c => c.FirstName == value).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Main program to show how it works

```
var customers = new List<Customer>
{
    new Customer { Id = 1, FirstName = "Foo", LastName = "Bar" },
    new Customer { Id = 2, FirstName = "Mark", LastName = "Whoknows" },
    new Customer { Id = 3, FirstName = "Ronald", LastName = "McDonald" },
};

var userWithFirstNameOfRonald = customers.GetByFirstName("Ronald");

Console.WriteLine(userWithFirstNameOfRonald.ToString());
```

This should print "Customer Is Ronald McDonald".  The important parts are commented.  The Class that contains the method should be static and the method needs to be static.  Along with that the first parameter of the method needs to be `this` to signal it is an extension method.  This will allow you to call it on the specific type you put for the first parameter.

Comment: This isn't going to work with Linq to Entities.  L2E doesn't know how to translate it to SQL.

Comment: @MystereMan Do you mean that the entity would become detached from the context?  That is a common problem and you can just re-attach the object.